# NodeJS Display live TCP data on dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

My ultimate goal is the following: my gardener has several devices that can send data to my Node.js server via TCP. This data is in JSON format, and looks something like the following:

Device A:

`{"pagename": "spacekittens", "count": 11};`

Device B:

`{"pagename": "norwegiansultans", "count": 22};`

As each of these are streamed to my server via TCP, I have added a `;` to separate each stream. In addition, the `count` in each device stream is randomly generated.

Now, I want to add dynamic routes for each TCP packet that comes my way, and display content from that stream to that route.

So my route `myserver:4000/spacekittens` should show the following:

`{"pagename": "spacekittens", "count": [random number every second]};`

And my route `myserver:4000/norwegiansultans` should show:

`{"pagename": "norwegiansultans", "count": [random number every second]};`

In order to accomplish this I have set up the following code:

```
server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    let chunk = "";
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        chunk += data.toString(); // Add string on the end of the variable 'chunk'
        let d_index = chunk.indexOf(';'); // Find the delimiter

        // While loop to keep going until no delimiter can be found
        while (d_index > -1) {
            try {
                let string = chunk.substring(0, d_index); // Create string up until the delimiter

                // define local variables that can be used in a closure
                let json = JSON.parse(string); // Parse the current string
                let localData = data;
                console.log(json.pagename); // Function that does something with the current chunk of valid json.    
                app.get("/" + json.pagename, function(req, res) {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                    });
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(json));
                    res.end();
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            chunk = chunk.substring(d_index + 1); // Cuts off the processed chunk
            d_index = chunk.indexOf(';'); // Find the new delimiter
        }
    });
    socket.on("close", function() {
        console.log("connection closed");
    });
});
```

I appreciate any thoughts and comments on methodology with regards to what I am trying to accomplish. However, I did not post only for this reason. I have a problem.

Currently, my `res.write()` line only populates the data in my routes one time. Adding new data via sockets does not replace the content on my route.

So under the `myserver:4000/spacekittens` route my `count` shows 11, and even though I stream an updated number `("count": 12)` my route `myserver:4000/spacekittens` still only shows 11. Console logging gives me the correct response each time data is sent. So I am not using the `res.write()` correctly since it does not override old data.

Unsure how to rectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would seperate the pages data and route setup from the connection handling. You can't set the same route up every time you receive a JSON blob so this modifies the app route to return the data to the user. The data will change with each blob of JSON.

```
class Pages {

    constructor(app){
        this._store = {}
        this.app = app
    }

    get( name ){
        return this._store[name]
    }

    set( name, data ){
        if ( !this.exists(name) ) this.setupRoute(name)
        return this._store[name] = data
    }

    exists( name ){
        return this._store.hasOwnProperty(name)
    }

    addJSON( json_string ){
        let data = JSON.parse(json_string)
        if ( !data.pagename ) throw new Error('No pagename in data: "%s"', json_string)
        if ( !data.count ) throw new Error('No count in data "%s"', json_string)
        return this.set(data.pagename, data)
    }

    setupRoute( name ){
        let route = `/${name}`
        this.app.get(route, (req, res)=>{
            res.json(this.get(name))
        })
        console.log('setup route: %s', route)
        return this.app
    }

}
```

Then the connection handling just deals with pulling out the JSON strings for `Pages`.

```
const pages = new Pages(app)

server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    let chunk = "";

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        chunk += data.toString(); // Add string on the end of the variable 'chunk'
        let d_index = chunk.indexOf(';'); // Find the delimiter

        // While loop to keep going until no delimiter can be found
        while (d_index > -1) {
            try {
                let string = chunk.substring(0, d_index); // Create string up until the delimiter
                pages.addJSON(string)
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
            chunk = chunk.substring(d_index + 1); // Cuts off the processed chunk
            d_index = chunk.indexOf(';'); // Find the new delimiter
        }
    });

    socket.on("close", function() {
        console.log("connection closed");
    });
});
```

You could also use one of the line delimited JSON parsing libraries which will take a binary stream and emit the JSON out as plain objects:

[ndjson](https://github.com/maxogden/ndjson) or [ld-jsonstream](https://github.com/timkuijsten/node-ld-jsonstream)

Comment: this definitely works on my localhost server. however, if i use this on my live site I run into a few issues. first, it takes several times sending to create the new routes `setup route: /spacekittens`. and once that is done, no amount of sending packets updates the route's information.

Comment: You might be getting more `data` chunks for each message away from localhost